# Selecting ambiguous column from subquery

Tags: sql, greenplum

Suppose we have the following query:

```
       select c.a, c.b, c.d
        from
           (select * from 
             tab1 join tab2
             on tab1.id = tab2.id)c
```

I get the following error:  `ERROR: 42702: column reference "d" is ambiguous`

How would I fix this? Can I do something like  `c.tab1.id` ?

Comment: You should change `SELECT *` to `SELECT t1.a, t1.b, t2.d FROM tab1 t1....`. Don't use `SELECT *` and use table alias.

Answer (score 0):

You may write your query like:

```
SELECT a, b, d FROM (SELECT tab1.a AS a, tab1.b AS b, tab2.c AS c, tab2.d AS d
FROM tab1 JOIN tab2 ON tab1.id = tab2.id)c;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is happening because both `tab1` and `tab2` have a column called `d`.

The simplest solution is to eliminate the subquery:

```
select ?.a, ?.b, ?.d
from tab1 join
     tab2
     on tab1.id = tab2.id
```

The `?` is a placeholder for the table where the column comes from.

If you need the subquery, then you should similarly use qualified column names instead of `select *`, so you identify where the columns are coming from.